# WAS-Active Directory Reason for Authentication failure

Tags: java, active-directory, websphere, websphere-6.1

I am using form based authentication with Websphere Application Server and Active Directory. Authentication can fail because of variety of reason viz.

1. user/password incorrect
2. Password expired
3. Account locked because of some pre set invalid password entry.

Is there a way to know the exact reason for authentication failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out and see if any of the info (particularly in the programming hints and tips helps you out).

Using a LoginFilter with relevant code should likely be the approach if you want to see the various reasons for the failure.

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/wes/pdf/0611_botzum-WAS-60-security-programming-hints.pdf

HTH

Manglu